# Add many rows with changed one column - Entity Framework with Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I've got table Player and table Achievments. All Players have group of same achievments but with other achievment state. What's best way to add new player and add the same group achievments rows for this player like for others but with other specified column value ?

First, i check does Player exist:

```
  int PlayerID = (from p in db.Players where (p.Hashedkey == player_data.hashed_data) select p.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

//if not, i create new Player

```
  if (PlayerID == 0) {
                Players player = new Players()  { AvatarImageUrl= player_data.avatar_url, DisplayName = player_data.mail
                , Email = player_data.mail , Hashedkey= player_data.hashed_data, Kind = "games::player"};
```

Player have property:

```
public virtual ICollection<Achievments> Achievments { get; set; }
```

with column PlayerID

When i create new Player I want create 100 Achievments for this Player and add to table Achievments. All Columns are the same like in other players achevments, only AchievmentState and PlayerID are other. I'm looking for best way to do this with minimum sql queries

Comment: Can you add an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Jonny my first idea is add player, get him id and get list of achievments for default player, change values and add to table. i edited question to show i what exactly i want achieve

Comment: Is there a table with the list of achievements? Or are you getting all the achievements from a default player? If you are doing this, I would suggest changing your database scheme. If you need further help, feel free to start a chat with me.